# How far in the past extundelete can go?

Tags: data-recovery, ext4

Yesterday I've accidentally deleted files from ext4 partition. During this time some downloading was running. If the content cannot be recovered I would be glad just for file names which were deleted. Is it worth to extundelete give a chance? My files were located under /home/wakatana/downloads/. I understand that I need to umount /home and restore files to some another place.

1. What options should I use with extundelete? If I understand correct this should be fine:

   # extundelete need the relative dir path

   me:/location_on_disk_where_backup_data_will_be-saved # extundelete --restore-directory --after $(($(date +%s) - 48*3600)) wakatana/downloads/ /dev/partition_which_contains_deleted_directory
2. Is it safe to run extundelete on partition where data was deleted or
   is backup advised or in another words does extundelete make some writings to unmounted partition?
3. Is there any live USB distro which contains extundelete?

Comment: Why don't you just give it a try?

Comment: My understanding is that undelete works until the affected parts of the disk is overwritten.   You should (at minimum) be able to use a standard ubuntu live distro, and apt-get install extundelete

Comment: I will give it a try. Mosrt important question remains: do I need to backup unmounted partition? Thanks

Comment: It should be a read only operation, so I assume no. It will get back anything that hasnt been overwritten and maybe corrupt files that have partially been.